# Jmeter - How do I reset counter under a for each controller?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am hitting the http request that has 2 dynamic variables under for each controller.

1. One Variable value is from for each controller and another one is from Jmeter counter function variable- looks like this -**${hostResponse}/${_*V(account*${__counter(,)})}**
2. I am performing multiple url requests from csv file and here, for first row request, the hostReponse and account-counter values are iterating and updating correctly up to 18 times as per my requirement.
3. Now for 2nd row of request-the account-counter value is not resetting and starting from first. It is continuing as account_19,account_20,account_21....

As I am newbie to Jmeter,can someone suggest the idea on resetting the counter variable after every complete iteration.

[Here is the test plan structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brIg7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) generates an incremented number **each time it's being called** therefore you either need to pass another argument to store the generated number into a separate [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
${__counter(,counter2)}
```

and then reference the value as `${counter2}` where required

or even remove this function completely as ForEach Controller is exposing its current iteration via `${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx}` since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

[image]

Comment: Hello Dmitri and Michal, Thanks for your time and response. I am bit confused with the suggestion as how to implement .I have updated my test plan structure to my post above. In my case am trying to hit the Http requests which are in csv file. For 1st row of request,i will get the json response with respect to 18 accounts. All those 18 accounts will be again sending as a separate http request . till then, the counter function is working fine. But from 2nd row, the counter function is keep on increasing with the continuation as account_19,account_20 .....Kindly suggest the way of implementation